# Add dynamic attribute value (or css selector value) in style using scss lang in Vue 3?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs3

I have a list of elements that have the same className and a specific id. Something like that:

```
<script setup lang="ts"> 
    const currentSelectedId = ref(1); 
</script> 
<template> 
<row class="b-grid-row" data-id="1"></row> 
<row class="b-grid-row" data-id="2"></row> 
<row class="b-grid-row" data-id="3"></row> 
</template> 
<style lang="scss"> 
:deep(.b-grid-row data-id="${currentSelectedRowId}") : { 
background-color: "blue"; 
} 
</style>
```

I also have a state called `currentSelectedRowId`, and I want to style the row with `data-id` attribute equal to `currentSelectedRowId`. How can I do that? Please advice!

Comment: please share the script

Comment: Please edit the question with formatted code

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim , please take a look, I edited the question.

Comment: the classnames and data-id are generated by UI library, I just show up here for more specific. I using Bryntum grid lib btw

Answer (score 0):

Try to use conditional class binding as follows :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const currentSelectedId = ref(1);
</script>
<template>
  <row  v-for="i in 3" :class="{selected:i===currentSelectedId}" class="b-grid-row" data-id="1"></row>
</template>
<style lang="scss">
.b-grid-row.selected{
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```